# React is not rendering this.state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and also to stackoverflow,

I am trying to render this.state.searchResults as attached code

The code runs without any error, but does not render. what wrong am I doing here ?

I am exporting this component in my main js file. if I run without map method, it renders correctly.

please help

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6JdU.png)

```js
    export class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            searchResults:  [
              {name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1},
              {name:' name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2},
              {name: 'name3', artist: 'artist3', album: 'album3', id: 3}
            ] 
          }
        }

      render() {
        return (
        <div>  
          <h1>Ja<span class="highlight">mmm</span>ing </h1>      
          <div className="App">       
            { this.state.searchResults.map( track => {
                return track
              })
            } 
          </div>
        </div>
        
      );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Instead, post it just as text.

Comment: *"The code runs without any error"* -  I would fully expect this to produce an error.  Are you sure you're checking the browser console for errors?  Because an object by itself is not valid as a renderable element in React.  Even if it did render, it wouldn't know *how* to render an object other than as something like `[object Object]`.

Comment: @David, you are correct. Browser console is throwing this error "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child........."

Comment: @pAtel0158: It's because `track` by itself in that context is an object, and React doesn't know how you want to render it.  You can render individual values from the object, or pass the object to a component which internally renders individual values from the object.  But an object by itself is not renderable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render object directly in JSX. Specify the object value

```
this.state.searchResults.map((track) => (
<p>{track.name} {track.artist} {track.album} </p>
))
```

Comment: this works, thanks Khant for replying.

Comment: @pAtel0158 You should select this answer as answered and close the question. NOT delete